# HTML <select> option to fill a textarea with HTML content

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using the code below found on JSFiddle, which works fine but when I implement it with my code which is a text area supporting HTML it doesn't seem to work.
This is the code I want to implement it into, but its not working. Can anyone advise?
My Code:

```
<div text-angular="text-angular" name="htmlcontent" ng-model="htmlcontent" ta-disabled='disabled'></div>
  <p>
    <textarea type ="text" id="message" ng-model="htmlcontent" required="required" style="display: none;" name="message" required /></textarea>
  </p>
```

JSFIDDLE HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="text1">text1</option>
    <option value="text2">text2</option>
    <option value="text3">text3</option>
    <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>
```

JSFIDDLE JS:

```
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

mydropdown.onchange = function(){
  mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value;
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Describe "isn't working"?

Comment: When I click one of the drop down options, the text area is not filled. I think its due to text Angular

Comment: are you doing in angular ?

Comment: Using text-angular to make the text area except html input?

Answer (score 1):

to acces to drop down element value  use this

```
mydropdown.options[mydropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

and when you concat to text area add a space  to good view

```
 mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value +' '+ mydropdownValue;
```

see the code

```js
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('message');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

mydropdown.onchange = function() {
  var mydropdownValue = mydropdown.options[mydropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + ' ' + mydropdownValue;
}
```

```html
My Code:
<div text-angular="text-angular" name="htmlcontent" ng-model="htmlcontent" ta-disabled='disabled'></div>
<p>
  <textarea type="text" id="message" ng-model="htmlcontent" required="required" style="display: block;" name="message" required /></textarea>
</p>
</div>
HTML JSFIDDLE:

<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="text1">text1</option>
    <option value="text2">text2</option>
    <option value="text3">text3</option>
    <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have included the code you have above, but its not working for me. I think the text area supporting HTML or the text Angular is causing the issue. Can you advice?

Comment: you text area ID is 'message'  , you need call that when in you JS write 'document.getElementById'    , like that document.getElementById('message');

Comment: Yes I've changed that. Its not the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from the event like so:

```
mydropdown.onchange = function(e){
    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + e.value;
}
```

Comment: So the JS should be like this?
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext');
        var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

     mydropdown.onchange = function(e){
    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + e.value;
}

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = document.getElementById('message');
var drop = document.getElementById('dropdown');
drop.addEventListener('change',function(e){
text.value += ' ' + e.target.value;
//OR ` ${e.target.value}`
})
```

```html
<div text-angular="text-angular" name="htmlcontent" ng-model="htmlcontent" ta-disabled='disabled'></div>
<p>
  <textarea type="text" id="message" ng-model="htmlcontent" required="required" style="display: block;" name="message" required /></textarea>
</p>
</div>
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="text1">text1</option>
    <option value="text2">text2</option>
    <option value="text3">text3</option>
    <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>
```