# change html content to selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to change the value of my product_name to be what it currently is + the name of the size but I have not been able to do that. I have tried using [HTML <select> option to fill a textarea with HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670615/html-select-option-to-fill-a-textarea-with-html-content) this but failed.

This is the HTML and I am trying to change the Product Name to Product Name + whatever option is selected from the options. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('name');
var drop = document.getElementById('dropdown');
drop.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  text.value += ' ' + e.target.value;
  //OR ` ${e.target.value}`
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTS -->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="sc-product-item thumbnail">

    <div class="caption">
      <h4 id="name" data-name="product_name">Product Name</h4>
      <p data-name="product_desc">Yellow</p>
      <hr class="line">

      <div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Size: </label>
          <select id="dropdown" name="product_size" class="form-control input-sm">
            <option>Iphone 11 6.1</option>
            <option>IPhone 11 Pro 5.8</option>
            <option>Iphone 11 Pro Max 6.5</option>
            <option>Iphone X</option>
            <option>Iphone XS</option>
            <option>Iphone XS Max</option>
            <option>Iphone XR</option>
            <option>Iphone 7</option>
            <option>Iphone 8</option>
            <option>Iphone 7 Plus</option>
            <option>Iphone 8 Plus</option>
            <option>Iphone 6</option>
            <option>Iphone 6s</option>
            <option>Iphone 6 Plus</option>
            <option>Iphone 6s Plus</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: There are no `#name` or `#dropdown` elements in your code so the error there is clear, as you can see in the snippet. Please edit the question to include all the relevant code

Comment: There is no `#name` element either.

Comment: I accidentally used the wrong one I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your JS elements IDs, and change `text.value` to `text.textContent`. Also, make sure you're replacing the text each time, not adding to it (i.e. `text.textContent = 'Product Name: ' + ...`):

```js
var text = document.getElementById('name')
var drop = document.getElementById('dropdown')
drop.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  text.textContent = 'Product Name: ' + e.target.value
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caption">
  <h4 data-name="product_name" id="name">Product Name</h4>
  <p data-name="product_desc">Yellow</p>
  <hr class="line">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Size: </label>
    <select id="dropdown" name="product_size" class="form-control input-sm">
      <option>Iphone 11 6.1</option>
      <option>IPhone 11 Pro 5.8</option>
      <option>Iphone 11 Pro Max 6.5</option>
      <option>Iphone X</option>
      <option>Iphone XS</option>
      <option>Iphone XS Max</option>
      <option>Iphone XR</option>
      <option>Iphone 7</option>
      <option>Iphone 8</option>
      <option>Iphone 7 Plus</option>
      <option>Iphone 8 Plus</option>
      <option>Iphone 6</option>
      <option>Iphone 6s</option>
      <option>Iphone 6 Plus</option>
      <option>Iphone 6s Plus</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ricardo could be a million different things. Check the console for errors, try to eliminate possible issues to see what could be causing it, etc.